# How to access a Sharepoint list from PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, list, web-services, sharepoint

I'm trying to get data from a SharePoint list from my PHP website, which contains a MySQL database. The list contains data which can be stored in the MySQL database.

Here are 2 solutions I thought of, but I'm also unsure of their possibility:

1. Using a webservice to reach the SharePoint list from PHP.
2. Connecting PHP's MySQL database with SharePoint's list so that they communicate with one another. But I don't know how to go about doing this solution.

Does anyone know how to improve on the above mentioned solutions? Or provide any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Look into the Business Connectivity Service.  It allows you to configure a database table as an external list.  To the user's they will be working with a SharePoint list but behind the scenes, the list is actually a representation of the database table with direct crud functionality.